# AutoMapper Exclude Fields

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying to map one object to another but the object is quite complex. During development, I'd like the ability to either exclude a bunch of fields and get to them one by one or be able to specify to map only fields I want and increase that as each test succeeds.

So:

```
class    
    string field1    
    string field2    
    string field3
```

Now I'd like to map `field1`, test, fix and then move onto `field2` then `field3`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
.ForMember(dto => dto.field1, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

Comment: how about the other way around? for example, the field1 does exits in viewmodel but not in the EF and still want to exclude field1 being mapped ?

Comment: Answering too late, user384080, you don't have to explicitly map the field. It will have framework's default value.