# Map readonly fields with Automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I have two identical classes in different namespaces:

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
class Class1
{
    public readonly int field1;
    public Class1(int value) { field1 = value; }
}
```

And the same class definition in namespace `ClassLibrary2`.

When I try to use AutoMapper, I get this exception:

> Expression must be writeable Parameter name: left

This is the code of AutoMapper:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ClassLibrary1.Class1, ClassLibrary2.Class1>();
var result = Mapper.Map<ClassLibrary2.Class1>(class1);
```

But if I try this [AutoMapper Exclude Fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146606/automapper-exclude-fields) it doesn't work, using this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ClassLibrary1.Class1, ClassLibrary2.Class1>()
    .ForMember(a => a.field1, a => a.Ignore());
```

For sure it works to change it to a property with public get and private set (like in [Automapper ignore readonly properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19681768/automapper-ignore-readonly-properties)), but I want to prevent a future developer of setting the value after constructor.

Is there any way of solving this using AutoMapper?

Comment: You can use a custom mapping: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046442/mapping-readonly-child-collection-with-automapper

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you'd like to set the property in the constructor, use `.ConstructUsing` and then ignore the field:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ClassLibrary1.Class1, ClassLibrary2.Class1>()
    .ConstructUsing(cls1 => new ClassLibrary2.Class1(cls1.field1))
    .ForMember(a => a.field1, a => a.Ignore());
```